# Web page download automation in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

How would you automate logging into a website and downloading a page using vbscript?

Comment: I doubt that you will find that much help, considering this is a technique usually reserved for malicious usage (bots, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Using the MSXML.XMLHTTP-object to first do a POST to login and then add the cookie-headers to a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick and dirty solution, you could use a Shell object with SendKeys and Run as [demonstrated here](http://computerperformance.co.uk/ezine/ezine26.htm). These functions are quite powerful for those situations where you just can't the right object or library to use...

Answer (score 0):

Well the script (given on link )works fine if you open the notepad and don't change the focus to other window.
If you change the focus above script doesn't work.